# Failing to release URL resource in Java

Tags: java, resources

As part of my unit tests I need to create some JAR files, perform actions on them, and then delete them (so that the folder is clean for the next test).

One of my actions enumerates the resources by looking at the manifest of jar files in these test folders.

```
manifests = _loader.getResources(MANIFEST_PATH);
while (manifests.hasMoreElements())
    {
        manifests.nextElement();
        //do some stuff here

    }
```

If I comment out manifests.nextElement(), everything is deleted as expected everytime.  If I leave it in, the jar files that it searches through aren't deleted.

I've tried grabbing the URL and closing the stream, but this didn't help.  I've looked at the resource patterns on SO, but I'm new to Java and am not sure which resource is caausing the hickup.

Thank you for any help.